# Can I have non-disposing code in a dispose method?

Tags: c#, dispose, idisposable

I have code analysis turned on and telling me to implement `Dispose()` correctly:

```
Modify 'UnitOfWork.Dispose' so that it calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize on the current object instance
```

It's actually implemented correctly, except for an additional line of code. See the first line (rolling back the transaction) in `Dispose()`. If I comment that line, the CA error goes away. If the line is uncommented, I get the error. Am I not allowed to have that line in `Dispose()`?

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // If the user never called commit, but we are using a transaction, then roll back.
        // If I comment this line, then the CA error about implementing `Dispose()` correctly goes away.
        if (!_commitOccurred && _useTransaction) { _transaction.Rollback(); }

        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this); // Already disposed; no need for the GC to finalize.
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool calledFromDisposeAndNotFromFinalizer)
    {
        if (_disposed) { return; }

        if (calledFromDisposeAndNotFromFinalizer)
        {
            if (_transaction != null) { _transaction.Dispose(); _transaction = null; }
            if (_connection != null) { _connection.Dispose(); _connection = null; }
        }

        _disposed = true;
    }
```

Comment: Put the cleanup code in the other Dispose, after `if (_disposed) { return; }` and inside `if (calledFromDisposeAndNotFromFinalizer)`.

Comment: The issue is that it wants you to have all the diposing code in `Dispose(bool)`, other than the SuppressFinalize.

Comment: Yep, that worked. Thanks, guys. Kind of embarrassed that I didn't see that myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleanup code goes in the overloaded `Dispose` :

```
 protected virtual void Dispose(bool calledFromDisposeAndNotFromFinalizer)
 {
    if (_disposed) { return; }

    if (calledFromDisposeAndNotFromFinalizer)
    {
        if (!_commitOccurred && _useTransaction) { _transaction.Rollback(); }
        if (_transaction != null) { _transaction.Dispose(); _transaction = null; }
        if (_connection != null) { _connection.Dispose(); _connection = null; }
    }

    _disposed = true;
 }
```

At very least this guarantees that redundant calls don't re-enter.